# Socket.ReadPacketASync

Tags: c#, socket, async-await

I'm working with TCP Sockets and I've build a simple packet struct that turns it into a datagram protocol. I've created a class which returns "promise" Tasks for Packets. Packets are very simple, they consist of:

```
struct TCPPacket
{
    unsigned short size; // contains size-1
                         // such that size ranges from 1 to 65536 bytes
    byte data[size];
}
```

Here is the implementation:

```
public class SocketASyncEventArgsEx
{
    private const int STATE_IDLE = 0;
    private const int STATE_RECEIVING = 1;
    private const int STATE_SENDING = 2;

    private SocketAsyncEventArgs e;
    private TaskCompletionSource<int> receiveTaskSource;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> sendTaskSource;

    private int state;

    private volatile byte[] buffer;
    private volatile int offset;
    private volatile int count;

    private byte[] size;

    public SocketASyncEventArgsEx()
    {
        e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        e.Completed += E_Completed;
        size = new byte[sizeof(ushort)];
    }

    public Task<int> ReceivePacketAsync(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (socket == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("socket");
        if (buffer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
        if (offset < 0 || offset > buffer.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset");
        if (count <= 0 || count > (ushort.MaxValue + 1) || count > buffer.Length - offset)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");

        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref state, STATE_RECEIVING, STATE_IDLE) != STATE_IDLE)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Operation already in progress.");

        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.count = count;

        receiveTaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        e.SetBuffer(size, 0, sizeof(ushort));
        socket.ReceiveAsync(e);

        return receiveTaskSource.Task;
    }

    public Task<bool> SendPacketAsync(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (socket == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("socket");
        if (buffer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
        if (offset < 0 || offset > buffer.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset");
        if (count <= 0 || count > (ushort.MaxValue + 1) || count > buffer.Length - offset)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");

        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref state, STATE_SENDING, STATE_IDLE) != STATE_IDLE)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Operation already in progress.");

        sendTaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.count = count;

        size[0] = (byte)((count - 1) >> 8);
        size[1] = (byte)((count - 1) >> 0);
        e.SetBuffer(size, 0, sizeof(ushort));
        socket.SendAsync(e);

        return sendTaskSource.Task;
    }

    private void E_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Receive)
            HandleReceiveCompleted(sender, e);
        else if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Send)
            HandleSendCompleted(sender, e);
    }

    private void HandleReceiveCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            if (e.BytesTransferred > 0)
            {
                int bytesLeft = e.Count - e.BytesTransferred;

                if (bytesLeft > 0)
                {
                    int byteOffset = e.Offset + e.BytesTransferred;
                    e.SetBuffer(byteOffset, bytesLeft);
                    ((Socket)sender).ReceiveAsync(e);
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] bufferRef = buffer;

                    if (bufferRef != null)
                    {
                        int packetSize = ((size[0] << 8) | (size[1] << 0)) + 1;

                        if (packetSize > count)
                        {
                            receiveTaskSource.TrySetException(new IOException("The buffer specified was not large enough."));
                            return;
                        }

                        buffer = null;
                        e.SetBuffer(bufferRef, offset, packetSize);
                        ((Socket)sender).ReceiveAsync(e);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        receiveTaskSource.TrySetResult(e.Offset + e.Count - offset);
                        Volatile.Write(ref state, STATE_IDLE);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                receiveTaskSource.TrySetResult(0);
                Volatile.Write(ref state, STATE_IDLE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            receiveTaskSource.TrySetException(new SocketException((int)e.SocketError));
            Volatile.Write(ref state, STATE_IDLE);
        }
    }

    private void HandleSendCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            if (e.BytesTransferred > 0)
            {
                int bytesLeft = e.Count - e.BytesTransferred;

                if (bytesLeft > 0)
                {
                    int byteOffset = e.Offset + e.BytesTransferred;

                    e.SetBuffer(byteOffset, bytesLeft);
                    ((Socket)sender).SendAsync(e);
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] bufferRef = buffer;

                    if (bufferRef != null)
                    {
                        buffer = null;
                        e.SetBuffer(bufferRef, offset, count);
                        ((Socket)sender).SendAsync(e);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sendTaskSource.TrySetResult(true);
                        Volatile.Write(ref state, STATE_IDLE);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sendTaskSource.TrySetResult(false);
                Volatile.Write(ref state, STATE_IDLE);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sendTaskSource.TrySetException(new SocketException((int)e.SocketError));
            Volatile.Write(ref state, STATE_IDLE);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, do the buffer, offset and count fields need to be volatile? The event callback `E_Completed` comes from a bound `ThreadPool` handle, which may be the same thread every time or a different thread every time.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have some code duplication in the `ReceivePacketAsync` and `SendPacketAsync` regarding the validation of the method parameters which should be extracted to a separate method.
- If you revert the condition of the first `if` in `HandleSendCompleted` and `HandleReceiveCompleted` you can return early and by omitting the `else` you will save some horizontal spacing.
- omitting braces `{}` although they are optional is considered to be bad practice which can bite you in the future.